# Remove all IIS error messages via <httpErrors> in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I'm implementing the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" prefixLanguageFilePath="" />
</httpErrors>
```

However I'd like to remove ALL IIS error pages so that none of my internal details are exposed on 404, 403, 500 etc.  I've tried to use:

```
<remove statusCode="*" />
```

To no avail.  Is there a standard solution here?

Comment: Try a `<clear />` as the first child node of `<httpErrors>` to remove all existing `<error>` nodes.

Answer (score 3):

As @Peter said, you can use the `<clear>` element.

> You can use the `<remove>` element to remove a specific error message from the collection of error messages your site or application inherits from a higher level in the IIS configuration hierarchy. Also, you can use the `<clear>` element to remove all HTTP error messages from the collection of HTTP error messages that your site or application inherits.

Reference: [iis.net](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)

Example:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <clear />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

(Side note: Virtual paths are not allowed in the `path` attribute of the `error` element.)